# Why was this post deleted by the community bot (but not as rude/spam)?

Tags: bug, specific-answer, rude-or-abusive

I recently encountered an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70813623/4032703) that was listed as being deleted by the community bot. The post is obvious trolling, and the user account was cleaned up.

Image for <10k:
[image]

That being said, the text wasn't hidden and it didn't say that it was deleted for being abusive or spam. Why is that?

Comment: can you add a picture for <10k rep like me?

Comment: @justANewbie it's an answer just saying `yes i will do this job i will have experience in this job and i have very good experience also i will do this job easily i have no problem` (that's the Google translate of the original Hindi)

Comment: @justANewbie Edited.

Comment: Probably the account was nuked and the posts associated with it went away as well.

Comment: @VLAZ Still, if the text had been particularly NSFW, it would've been nice if it had been hididen.

Comment: Probably. I'm just theorising on what most likely happened.

Comment: @VLAZ Yep, it says ["User destroyed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7knbG.png) in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70813623/timeline#history_c224de3e-bcc3-4c08-b77f-e8d854def325).

Comment: @EJoshuaS Here's a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216376/348196) about this from 2014.

Comment: You can see in the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70813623/timeline) that the account was destroyed

Comment: the user had two identical posts on the same question, one was marked as "spam or offensive" at 15.15.35Z, the other one (the one you ask about) was deleted a second later, so probably when the account was nuked.

Comment: Posting garbage is not trolling, not rude and not spam. It is simply destructive behavior, but it does not fall into any of these categories. Btw, google translate identifies the text as Hindi, although it can not give a comprehensive English translation. The post is very likely garbage also on Hindi.